# Is there a way to combine information from two columns into a single column in R?

Tags: r

I am working with a data set that has two columns, one of which will have useful information. The one without information will have NA as its value. I would like this information to go into a third column together. An example of the data would be as below

```
 1 NA NA
 2 NC NA
 3 NA Alabama
```

What would be a method to have the third column produce:

```
  1 NA
  2 NC
  3 Alabama
```

I tried paste(), but this yields the data below: The NAs in this case also become characters that say "NA".

```
 1 NA NA
 2 NC NA
 3 NA Alabama
```

Any ideas as to how to achieve the 2nd table as opposed to the third, with the NA values retaining their NA status instead of being a character string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `coalecse` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   transmute(coln = coalecse(col1, col2))
```